# regexp for c#, matching teams inside backspace

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having trouble with my c# code.

I have stored a string object when I print it out it prints out **"username"** and when I view it in the debugger it is shown as **"\"username\""**. How can I replace "\ with whitespace in the variable? It is stopping me from making comparison operations.

I tried with

```
memberNameStripped = teamMemberName.Replace(@"\", "");
```

But it does not replace the "\ so how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That doesn't look like regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why regex? Use [`String.Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9(v=vs.110).aspx) to remove leading and trailing quotes(`"`):

```
memberNameStripped = memberNameStripped.Trim('"');
```

It's efficient and clear.

Answer (score 2):

The \ is an escape character, what you probably want to replace is the double quote "

So try:

```
memberNameStripped = teamMemberName.Replace("\"", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

In debugger it is shown as "\"username\"" because it is a quoted string. This is why it prints out "username". You could get rid of quotes using Replace("\"", "")